# datetime.time convert hours place to minutes place

Tags: python, datetime

I have a set of data such as:

0. datetime.time(3,1)
1. datetime.time(5,22)
   ...

Due to data entry error the datetime.time(3,1) is supposed to be datetime.time(0,3,1), and the datetime.time(5,22) is supposed to be datetime.time(0,5,22). Basically the current number at the hour attribute should be at the minutes attribute, and the number at the minute attribute should be at the second attribute.

Is there any way to make the conversion in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fairly straight forward:

```
t = datetime.time(3,1)
t = datetime.time(0, t.hour, t.minute)
```

Note that hours can only go up to `24`, so any higher minutes would… have led to an error already? Be discarded?

And are you sure you aren't looking for a [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) instead?

Comment: It works for me. Luckily my data does not include minutes larger than 24.

Comment: Then it sounds like you're probably actually working with short *durations* and should be using `timedelta`…?